# Protractor: How to access global variables that we have inside our application?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Hope if someone could help. I am working on an Angular based application. I am automating my End to End tests with the help of Protractor. I have a global variable set in my Application called "selectedPlatform", which conveys, for which platform(iOS/Android) I have my current application build for.

I need to access this variable for me write my test cases accordingly. Any help on this ground is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: You've been down voted so your question will probably be deleted. Anyway, even globals are evil, is as simple as referencing like this: `global.selectedPlatform` good luck.

Comment: Hey Leo,Thanks for your response! But, I am unable to get to see the value of my variable when I accessed it as you mentioned above. Please clarify

Comment: As well, I am in the process of injecting the service which holds my choice of platform while building. But, I am not pretty sure how I can implement that in protractor. Could you advise on that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your variable is a global inside your website, i.e. it's on `window`. Generally, your end to end tests should avoid accessing variables directly in your site's code, but if you have to do this you can do:

```
browser.executeScript('return window.selectedPlatform')
```

Comment: Thanks Jmr, will try this and let you know the outcome.