# CKEditor + Protractor: Testing with Protractor can't find CKEditor instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, ckeditor, protractor

I am using Protractor for a non-Angular page and wanting to find the CKEditor instance on the page to then set data for. I can do this in Chrome console via:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.html_editor.setData("Hello")
```

In my test for the page, I have the code below:

```
it('should enter text in editor successfully', function() {

    var composerPage = new ComposerPage();

    browser.executeScript('return window.CKEDITOR');    
    window.CKEDITOR.instances.html_editor.setData( 'Hello' );        

  });
```

However, the error returned is:

> Error: Failed: Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined

I've already had a look at this Stack Overflow question here: [Protractor: How to access global variables that we have inside our application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241520/protractor-how-to-access-global-variables-that-we-have-inside-our-application?answertab=votes#tab-top) but didn't really help get me unstuck.

Any suggestions as to how I can define the CKEditor instance and set data would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `browser.executeScript()` to set the editor's data:

```
var value = 'Hello';
browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
    window.CKEDITOR.instances.html_editor.setData(arguments[0]); 
}, value);
```

Comment: Still getting ```Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined``` . Any other suggestions perhaps?

Comment: @RyanDrake how about `browser.executeScript("window.CKEDITOR.instances.html_editor.setData(arguments[0]);", value);`?

Comment: Same error. It causes all the tests to fail in this case.

Comment: @RyanDrake how does it fail? Are you sure you can access `CKEDITOR` through `window.CKEDITOR`?

Comment: Eventually got it working! Protractor wasn't working as intended with Angular v1.3.3, so updated to v1.3.15 (latest stable build) yesterday and it's now looking good. Thanks Alex!

Comment: @alecxe , I'm getting an error Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

Comment: I got it to working by reading the instance by the name in the title field. var statamentDes = 'Hello';
    browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
        var name = "editor1" // split title to get this
        window.CKEDITOR.instances[name].setData(arguments); 
    }, statamentDes);